# Проверка строки PHP на допустимые символы

Tags: php

Как проверить, чтобы строка содержала только цифры, буквы, -, или _ (без пробелов и иных символов?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
$str = 'проверяемая строка';
if (preg_match("#^[aA-zZ0-9\-_]+$#",$str)) {
   echo "Все верно";
} else {
   echo "Есть недопустимые символы";
}
?>
```

Как-то так.

Comment: _`aA-zZ0-9`_ - неправильно. Должно быть `A-Za-z0-9`.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ выше - нерабочий

```
$str = 'string to check';
if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+$/")) {
echo 'найдены только нужные символы (нужны: a-z, A-Z, 0-9, -, _)';
}
//https://regex101.com/r/sOqk8P/1

$str = 'string to check';
if (preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+/")) {
echo 'найдены неподходящие символы (не подходят все, кроме: a-z, A-Z, 0-9, -, _)';
}
//https://regex101.com/r/lY0846/1

//если требуются и русские буквы - учтите, что буква "Ё" не находится в группе А-Я, аналогично и "ё":
$str = 'проверяемая строка с русскими символами';
if (preg_match("/^[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z0-9\-_]+$/")) {
echo 'найдены только нужные символы (нужны: а-я, А-Я, a-z, A-Z, 0-9, -, _)';
}

$str = 'проверяемая строка с русскими символами';
if (preg_match("/[^а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z0-9\-_]+/")) {
 echo 'найдены неподходящие символы (не подходят все, кроме: а-я, А-Я, a-z, A-Z, 0-9, -, _)';
}
```

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/469253)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, как раз отвечает, а в принятом ответе действительно ошибка.

Comment: @asianirish, а если подумать?

Comment: @Qwertiy, это скорее на библиотеку копипаста на все случаи жизни похоже, а не ответ на вопрос.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, 4 способа проверки - на соответствие/несоответствие для латинского/кириллического случаев. Идеальный ответ.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, ну значит прислушался и поправил - тоже хорошо :)